# IntentHandler called with empty parameter

Tags: ios, swift, siri

I'm new to iOS development, and I'm trying to add support for Siri Shortcuts to my app with the purpose of allowing Siri to suggest a common user actions in the various "Siri Suggestions" widgets throughout iOS 14.

Using Apple's documentation and various other sources I managed to reach the point where I'm creating the intents, passing a parameter and donating the intent to the OS (in the form of `INInteraction`). So far, they haven't shown up in the widgets, but I can see the suggestions in the Siri search.

However, **when tapping the shortcut, my `IntentHandler` is called with an intent that's basically empty**. When I print the intent upon reception, it is of the right class, but it's parameter is empty.

**My intent definition**
[image]

**The StatusUpdate Type used as the intent's parameter**
[image]

**Intent donation code**

```
func donateInteraction(for status: StoredStatus) {
    //  Create the intent we're going to donate
    let intent = SetStatusIntent()
    // Create the status `type` associated with the intent, and add it to the intent
    let statusUpdate = StatusUpdate(identifier: status.uuid, display: status.status.asString)
    intent.status = statusUpdate
    
    let interaction = INInteraction(intent: intent, response: nil)
    // The identifier is used to match with the donation so the interaction
    // can be deleted if the status is removed.
    interaction.identifier = status.uuid
    
    interaction.donate { (error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error as Any)
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, I want the shortcut to arrive at the IntentHandler with some form of identifier for the action that the user performed. I figured this is what the parameters are for, but it doesn't seem to actually pass this parameter, even though the [suggestion in the search results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZI30.png) is specific to the interaction I've created.

I would love to know what I'm doing wrong here, and — additionally — if there's a reason the suggestions only show up in the search screen, and not any of the suggestions widgets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to some help of a friend I found that unchecking the "Intent is user configurable in the Shortcuts app…" option seemed to fix this for me.

Not sure why, this might be a bug on Apple's side. But it works!

Comment: Thanks. You are a life saver. I wonder if Apple even tests their features.